# How can I move files into a folder and take them out of the folder

Tags: bash

I have 1000 files which are with .txt format. 
I am trying to generate 1000 folder and put each of them into the folder

I can do the following

```
for i in $(seq 0 1000); do 
    mkdir -p "$i" && 
    mv *"$i".txt "$i"
done
```

however, it puts whatever has 0 in it into the folder . for example 
The files names are

```
TR0.txt
TR1.txt
TR2.txt
.
.
TR1000.txt
```

The above code will create 1000 folder but then it will put file TR0.txt, TR10.txt .... into the folder 0 etc
I want to put each file in a folder with its number

Then I want to take them all out of each folder and put them in another folder.

I do the following which does not work either

```
mkdir myfolder
 for dir in $(seq 0 1000); do
   mv -vi $i/* $myfolder
done
```

Comment: Just don't use a glob `*` in your `mv` command, but use the file name instead: `mv "TR$i.txt" "$i"`.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf what when I want to take them all out of each folder and put them in one folder ?

Comment: Is this 2 questions really? For each file ending in ".txt" in the current directory, you want to create a new directory whose name is the same as the file but without the extension and move the file into it. Later, in a second phase, you want gather up all files as distributed by the first question, and store them in some new directory.

Answer (score 0):

As said in a comment, don't use globbing. Instead, recreate the file name:

```
for i in $(seq 0 1000); do 
    mkdir -p "$i" && 
    mv "TR${i}.txt" "$i"
done
```

On the other side, to gather all the files in those folders and put them into another folder, the destination of the `mv` command must be a folder, not a variable that contains nothing (or something that is not a folder name):

```
mkdir myfolder
for dir in $(seq 0 1000); do
   mv -vi $i/* myfolder
done
```

Comment: Or instead of using the external `seq`, you could use brace expansion: `for dir in {0..1000}; do`